# Making real time socket.io Pong game faster

Tags: node.js, socket.io, real-time, pong

I just finished implementing the game Pong using node.js and socket.io for backend, with jQuery for client-side. I put the game on my free-tier AWS instance and the mechanics work fine but the latency is unplayable. In the game, the paddle of the player who controls it moves locally. The client-side also sends a server request which broadcasts paddle movement to the opponent every `requestFrameAnimation`. To launch the ball the player whose serve it is presses spacebar which sends a server request, which then emits to both players to start the ball movement.

Both the paddle movement and the ball launching are suffering from latency. For the paddles I think the problem is that I'm sending a server request every `requestFrameAnimation` which is probably to fast of a rate. Maybe I should make a setInterval that sends the player's paddle position to his opponent every fraction of a second. As for the ball, since the signal for it to start moving is sent by the server I think I need to send an actual time for the ball to launch ahead of the time the spacebar was pressed so each local machine can count down to that time.

Here is a snipped of my client-side code for some context:

```
function updateFrame(){
    paddleSpeed = 0;
    if (keysPressed.up){  // Move paddle up
        if (!(myPaddle.offset().top <= arena.offset().top)){  // Make sure paddle isn't at top 
            paddleSpeed -= 8;
        }
    }
    if (keysPressed.down) {  // Move paddle down
        if (!(myPaddle.offset().top+paddleL.height() >= arena.offset().top + arena.height())){  // Make sure paddle isn't at bottom
            paddleSpeed += 8;
        }
    }
    if (paddleSpeed != 0) socket.emit("moveReq", paddleSpeed);   // Send server request to be sent to opponent
    myPaddle.css({top: '+='+paddleSpeed+'px'});   // Move paddle locally
    if (gameInProgress){   // If round has started, move the ball
        ball.css({left: '+='+ballSpeed.hor+'px', top: '+='+ballSpeed.ver+'px'});
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateFrame);  // Request next frame
```

and my server-side:

```
socket.on('moveReq', function(data){
    socket.broadcast.emit("movePaddle", data);  // Send opponent's paddle movement to user
});

socket.on('launchGame', function(){   // Launch the game
    io.sockets.emit('startGame');
});
```

Does anybody have any tips to reduce the latency on my game, or is my free-tier just too low bandwidth for this sort of web app?

Comment: What aws region do you live in? What region are you services hosted in?  What aws region does your opponent live in? This could be contributing to the latency you're experiencing.

Comment: West coast NA. But even when I try this game on my localhost with a different computer connecting over wifi its laggy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be enough bandwidth to run this game easy, so I do not think that is your problem.

Instead I recommend you to take a look at [this](http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/fpm1.html) blog about online game developing. I used the ideas described in there myself when I started developing multiplayer games. It explains several key problems and solutions when developing online games.

Comment: Yea I think its something in my implementation becasuse when I run it through my localhost and connect with another computer over wifi it is still laggy.

Comment: As mentioned in the blog/article I linked earlier you probably want to add some kind of client side prediction to not be as dependent on server latency.

Comment: Hmm that sounds pretty complicated but I'll give it a try!